# Random-js is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Previously, everything worked, but now something is wrong.
Node version - 10.4
Error:

```
var random = require("random-js")();
                                 ^
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
```

Code:

```
var random = require("random-js")();
```

For this:

```
    function getRandom() {
    reGeneratePatern();
    gencode = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
    return gencode;
}
```

Wtf?

Comment: did you upgrade that module?

Comment: Yes (npm i random-js)

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious?

Comment: then change it back. or read the release notes.

Comment: On node v9 all worked... After UD this error @Salman A

Comment: sounds like `random-js` had a breaking change.

Comment: yep: https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-js#upgrading-from-10

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-js#nodejs) of this module you will notice it returns an object.

So you should use

```
var random = require("random-js");
```

If you want to get `Random` method you can use Object Destructuring

```
const { Random } = require("random-js");
```

Comment: Your decision is also true. But I set random-js 1.0.8, everything works as it should. Thank us for help!